# How to read integers separated by a comma and a white space into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I need a function that gets input in the form of *int1*, *int2*, *...*, *intn*.
I neeed to store the values of these integers in an array. A separate function is used to get the number of integers to be read. How can I make the two functions work?

If it's not clear, it's something like this:

function1 gets an integer to get the number of input to be read. Then the function2 will read that input *plus one* but the input must be in a single line and must be separated by a comma and/or a white space.

Function1 gets, for example *5*. function2 will want to read input like: *3, 21, 5, 1, 5, 2* and store it into a separate array for later use.

Can anyone help? Thanks. I thought of using loops but I remembered that the input must be in one line. Maybe scanf? With [^,]? But how do I make it work with the first function?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is I don't know what input the user will give the program. The only code I found(from other posts) was something like this


scanf("%4[^,],%4[^,],%79[^,],%d", sem, type, title, &value);

But what if the user gives '8' to the first function? The second function will have to read '8+1' integers.

Comment: And in another case, the user might input another number which means the code that reads the input will have to change again to accommodate the number of input. Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getInput(int sizeOfInput, int arr[]) {
  int i = 0;
   printf("IN");
  for(; i < sizeOfInput - 1; ++i) {
    scanf("%d, ", &arr[i]);
  }
  scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   printf("OUT");
}

main(){
  int sizeOfInput = 0;
  printf("Enter how many numbers do you want to enter?");
  scanf("%d", &sizeOfInput);

  int arr[sizeOfInput]; 
  getInput(sizeOfInput, arr);
}
```

Sorry I am lazy but for you to learn it would be the best to figure out what this code does before you use it, that is also a reason why I did not comment it.

Comment: Thanks. I get how it works. Haha,