# C - Input numbers in line splitted by comma

Tags: c

I need to load input from text which is in one line like:

```
5, 8, 8, 6, 7, ...
```

... to an array. (Numbers are separated by commas).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: `char array[1024]; fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin);` and send the input to the standard input. This is a very simple way because this just loads the input to an array and doesn't do any complicated conversion!

Comment: `fgets`, then `strtok`, alternatively `sscanf`. You should try something/research before you ask here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read integers separated by a comma and a white space into an array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981842/how-to-read-integers-separated-by-a-comma-and-a-white-space-into-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? Just take as input an integer array without commas. But if you want, then here is how to achieve it.
You can use a character array to keep such data. An integer array will not do.
Your input will be stored as:

```
char a[3];
a[0]='1';
a[1]=',';
a[2]='2';
```

So to take the input, first define a character array  `a[n]` of size `n`, then take the input as

```
while(i<n)
{
    a[i]=getchar();
    i++;
}
```

This will keep your data in the array as `a[n]={'1' , ',' , '2' , ',' upto n}`
You can then print them as

```
i=0;
while(i<n)
{
    putchar(a[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You give your input as:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

and the output will be:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

The even numbered indexes will contain the numbers and the odd numbered indexes will contain commas.